# how do i get a rightscale or EC2 AMI loaded onto my laptop?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rightscale

I like to develop locally on my laptop, but want to deploy to EC2/Rightscale.  What's the best way to load a rightscale or ec2 AMI onto my local desktop so that i can have a mirror copy of the cloud operating environment that I can develop against?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried converting an EC2 AMI to a local VM image, but you could work the other way around: create a local VM to do your development and then convert the VM image into an EC2 AMI.  Here's a [nice post](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/9/1/creating-an-new-ec2-ami-from-within-vmware-or-from-vmdk-files) that explains the process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an EBS-based AMI, make snapshots of it, and download the snapshots using this tool: https://cloudyscripts.com/tool/show/3

Answer (score 0):

You can try using vagrant. It uses Virtualbox to provision virtual machines and you can use chef-solo to run chef recipes on the virtual machine.